# Attachfile Ampscript function not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, attachment

My goal is to add an attachment to my email via ampscript.
That's why I was looking at this [guide](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/) and used this code:

```
var @fileName, @fileAlias set @fileName = "testAttach.doc" 
set @fileAlias = "testAttach_FTP.doc" AttachFile("FTP", @fileName, @fileAlias)
```

The file is present in my Import folder with the name testAttach.doc, 
Preview does not show any error but if I *send test* the email is not delivered (if I remove this code, the same email is delivered).
The file is very small 1KB.

What could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Quick Checks that you can do: 1. Is attach file provisioned for your account? 2. The file is present at the time of send and is not being modified or locked at the time of send? 3. Can you transfer the file on your local and see that it is not corrupted or anything?

Comment: You should get a notification email from Salesforce Support about a closed and open case describing reasons why the file can't be a attached in some time.

Comment: thanks @SwatiMishra, how can I check if attach file is provisioned?

Comment: @eeadev: You can check by raising a case with Salesforce or you can check with your account representative

Comment: If you click on your name, and go to support tools > Business Rules and search for email_attachments you can see if this is enabled for the account. @SwatiMishra

Comment: @EazyE are you referring to the top right corner in Marketing Cloud where Setup etc. can be found? I've never seen those items ("support tools > Business Rules").